# When .NET runtime closes (My)SQL connections from connection pool

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, connector-net

I recently read about connection pooling ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx), [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connection-pooling.html)).

The aim of a Connection Pool is that the MySQL clients should not be forced to constantly do connect and disconnect. Thus it is possible to cache a connection in the MySQL client when a user of the connection no longer needs it. Thus another user that needs a connection to the same MySQL Server can reuse this cached connection later on (by Mikael Ronstrom).

What this means is:

- I connect to MySQL server
- execute some queries
- call MySqlConnection.Close()
- at this point connection is not closed, it is kept in connection pool of the client (application). If I execute again MySqlConnection.Open(connection string), connection will be created/taken from the connection pool of the application (connection poll just returns instance of MySqlConnection).

I tested with this code:

```
 MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;uid=user;pwd=pass;database=dbname;Pooling=true");

 try
 {
   conn.Open();
   Console.WriteLine("Connected to sql server");
 }
 catch (MySqlException e)
 {
   Console.WriteLine("Error connecting to sql server ["+e.Message+"]");
 }

 MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from table1 where id = 1", conn);
 MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

 while (reader.Read())
 {
   string a = reader.GetString(0);
 }
 reader.Close();

 try
 {
   conn.Close();
 }
 catch (MySqlException e) {}

 // I connected to MySQL server via terminal and executed 'show full processlist'
 // connection was still present
 // If I add MySqlConnection.ClearAllPools(); connection was closed (everything as it should)
```

At which point does .NET runtime call connector MySqlConnection.ClearAllPools(); or MySqlConnection.ClearPool() static methods? These methods actually close connection with MySQL server. What happens in case .NET application crashes, does MySQL connection gets closed after wait_timeout has passed. Should I call ClearAllPool() at the end of application execution (last line).

Comment: As a general rule always use "using"..It will handle your connection and close it

Comment: @apomene I agree, thnx. Although in my case calling conn.Dispose() directly or automatically with using does not have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

From the MSDN link you have specified

> If the specified **MinPoolSize** is greater than zero, the connection pool is not destroyed until the **AppDomain** is unloaded and the process ends.

Further

> The pool is automatically cleared when a fatal error occurs, such as a failover.

As such, the connection would be cleaned up when the application exits.

You should be able to test this by making  a connection, verifying it is still open after using the `close()` method and then causing the application crash.

Comment: By destroying does this mean ClearAllPools() is actually called or .NET just kills opened TCP connections for this process.

Comment: @broadband The exact underlying procedure is not specified, but the documentation is explicit in saying `The pool is automatically cleared when a fatal error occurs, such as a failover.`, so it does clear the underlying structure and close the connections. I missed this on the first reading, have updated the answer.